# Не работает MvcHtmlString в MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Не работает `MvcHtmlString` в MVC 6

Не может найти пространство имён `MvcHtmlString`

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

...

public static class PagingHelpers

    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                              GamePagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                              Func<int, string> pageUrl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MvcHtmlString` - это обертка, которую добавили поверх `HtmlString` в целях   совместимости. Теперь ее убрали.

Используйте `HtmlString` (`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlString`).